# Create Databse in Windows from command-line or VBScript?

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, cmd, vbscript

How to create a new database for PostgreSQL 10 (pgAdmin 4) from command-line or VBScript in Windows?

I used the following command from command-line:

```
pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:123@localhost:5432/myDB --format=p --clean
```

But it returned the following error:

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "myDB" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

How to run the server in "localhost" (127.0.0.1)? How to fix this?

**EDIT:**
Furthermore, I also tried this,

```
createdb --dbname=postgresql://postgres:123@localhost:5432/myDB --format=p --clean
```

And got this error,

> createdb: illegal option --
>   dbname=postgresql://postgres:123@localhost:5432/myDB
>
> Try "createdb --help" for more information.

Comment: Ummm... what gave you the idea `pg_dump` would *create* a database? Perhaps surprisingly, PostgreSQL databases are created with the `createdb` tool.

Comment: [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers), I have updated the question. Can you check it?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-createdb.html) yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209147/how-to-prevent-asking-for-password-when-creating-new-database-in-postgresql-10) thanks to [Jasen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/67180/jasen) and [Mladen Uzelac](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/51803/mladen-uzelac). This is the command-line to create the database,

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin"
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb" "user=postgres dbname=postgres password=something_secret"
```